# Callkit , how to disable video button when locking screen?

Tags: video, lockscreen, callkit

As new feature of iOS10, CallKit is powerful. When the screen is locked, how can I disable the "Video" Button ? like the pic bottom：
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy86N.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can set CXProviderConfiguration class property "supportsVideo" to NO, like below.

```
CXProviderConfiguration *configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc]initWithLocalizedName:@"app name"];
configuration.supportsVideo = NO;
```

It will disable video feature.

Update:
Set **CXCallUpdate** property "**hasVideo**" to NO. and remove **remoteHandle** also. 
Note: If you remove remoteHandle property, you can't call back from Recents log.

Comment: no, if i set "supportsVideo" to NO, it just become "FaceTime" button and is still enable to click.

Comment: Check all the places wherever you used CXProviderConfiguration object. You have to set supportsVideo in reportIncomingCallWithContact method also. Remove INStartVideoCallIntent If you set in the info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

You must set supportsVideo property in CXProviderConfiguration to NO. 
And non set supportedHandleTypes.

Comment: it just become "FaceTime" button and is still enable to click.

Comment: You must leave supportedHandleTypes property to disable Facetime button.

Comment: How? supportedHandleTypes  just supports CXHandleTypeGeneric、CXHandleTypePhoneNumber、CXHandleTypeEmailAddres.